# Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7 refuses all outside tcp connections

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp, connection

I am unable to connect, for example, via http to a brand new installation of 64-bit Windows Server 2008. The server is on a domain, but is not DC (that's another problem altogether).

The IIS7 is running on the server and the website is accessible locally via http://localhost, but when I try to connect from another machine on the same network, the connections is refused, even though Windows Firewall is disabled.

I am able to connect to and browse the shared folders on the server using Windows Explorer, so it is not a physical connection issue. I can ping other machines on the network from the server, but trying to ping the server from another machine results in "Destination host unreachable".

As far as I can tell, the server refuses any TCP connections from any machine. I am thinking, there must be some other configuration setting that I am missing... Please, help.

NS

Comment: the firewall is complete off for all profiles?

Comment: Yes, it's completely off in all of them.

Comment: when you say same network does that mean same subnet?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software on the server or across your network? It may have a built-in firewall that is blocking HTTP inbound (or outbound)

Comment: @Ashley, No, no anti-virus. Other machines communicate just fine, including an ancient W2003 Server.

Comment: @tony, yes, the same 0.0.0.255 subnet.

Comment: When you say you can connect to Shared Folders on the machine using Windows Explorer, is that using `\\<hostname>`, `\\<hostname>.<domain>.<tld>` or `\\<ip address>`? Do all of the listed methods work? Also, have you verified that its gateway, DNS and any VLAN configuration is all in line? Also, do the DNS/Active Directory servers get a DNS registration (or WINS registration) from the machine and if so, when you run `arp -a` to display the ARP table (on one of the DCs), can you see the MAC address of the server and does it match what it should be? Can you Remote Desktop to the machine?

Comment: Finally, are there any Filtering Platform alerts in the security event log?

Comment: @Ashley, It seems I can connect with `\\<hostname>`, `\\<ip-addr>`, but not with `\\<hostname>.<domain>.<tld>`. Gateway and DNS are fine, I suppose, since one can connect to the Internet and to other machines on the subnet from the server in question. No VLAN, afaict. Running arp, I can see the server and it appears correct. Curiously, Remote Desktop is being refused via `hostname`, but allowed via `ip-address`. No Filtering Platform alerts, though. Needless to say, I am confused.

Comment: Additionally, I just discovered that tracert from a workstation to the server name resolves to an incorrect IP address. It appears that another computer with the same name used to be on the network, and the address resolves incorrectly (to the old one) in some contexts. How do I fix that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to investigate DNS and WINS to ensure that they are dynamically updating properly or allowing registration from "secure clients". But for now, delete any incorrect records in both manually, then recreate statically with what they should be. Try all of the above again. It may be being denied via hostname because of the old name match up and DNS confusion. Especially if you're only allowing machines to connect that support [NLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Level_Authentication)

Comment: At this point I'm starting to wonder whether it would be better use of your time to scrap the machine and reinstall (potentially with a new name). I'd also make sure that you (or whoever is in charge of your DNS and WINS) check that dynamic updating and scavenging are enabled so that new computers are able to register themselves against to DNS and old computers' records aren't kept.

Comment: @Ashley, Well you won't believe what actually resolved the problem... :-) Renaming the machine to something never previously used on that network. That's it. Everything (well, almost) now magically works. ALthough you haven't explicitly told me to do it ("scrap the machine" ouch! ;-), the conversation with you has led me to this embarrassignly simple solution. Thank you very much for your time. If you want to, post a summary answer and I will mark it preferred - you deserve the credit.

Comment: Great to hear you've resolved the issue. I'd be interested to see what we could discover about why the name is a problem - you should try spin something new up (if you have VM space handy) and see if you can reproduce the issue? I will post a summary answer now :)

Comment: Have added the summary answer as requested. @NonSequitur :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to figuring out what was wrong:

- Checking there was no firewall or antivirus solution with a built-in firewall
- Checked that file share access was possible via `\\<hostname>`, `\\<hostname>.<domain>.<tld>` or `\\<ip address>`
- Checked that DNS and WINS registration was working properly and that both contained the correct references to the server in question

  - Ie, does a DNS request on the FQDN resolve the right IP address and does a WINS/NetBIOS request for the hostname resolve the right IP
- Checked `arp -a` to ensure that computers communicating with the server were able to see its MAC address correctly
- Does remote desktop work?
- Are there any filtering platform warnings or failure audits in the security event log of the server?

In the end, a name change of the machine was necessary to fix. It turns out the name of the machine had been used on the domain in the past and may have some skeletons left around.

Suggestion is to figure out what those skeletons are to help prevent issues like this in the future.

EDIT: Just so its clear, this is a summary from the comments on the original question

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it is fixed.

Short answer, it was due COM+.  My post [here](http://www.alfredivy.per.sg/blogger/?p=1321).

Comment: Hmm, I wish this were it, but - alas - no. My symptoms are nowhere near as severe as you describe. Everything seems to be working normally, except for inbound TCP connections. And I seem to have all the registry keys under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EventSystem\<guid>\EventClasses intact. In short, I don't think it's COM+ - and it's a brand-new installation of WS2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server and test machines all in the same subnet, subnet masks and default gateway correct?
Are there any static routes in the server?
Are there any errors in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line run "netstat -n -a -b" and check:
which addresses are listening on port 80
which process is doing the listening

You bindings for the website may be on the wrong ip address or another app may have already started listening on 0.0.0.0:80 or :80  (i have seen apps like skype grab 80/443 because it is usually open thru the firewall)

W2k8 typically enables ipv6, check out the connections etc to ensure either your ipv4 is enabled or that your test machines are ipv6 enabled

Did you add 'localhost' as the hostname header in the bindings?